# Issues passing registry key from variable to REG DELETE in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry

we have admin usernames (*.admin) that we use to log into user's computer but I'd like to get rid of any profile that might create so I've made this little logoff script. The thing is I'm having issues passing a registry key in a variable to the command "**`REG DELETE`**". Here's my code :

```
@ echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion


CD %systemdrive%\users
FOR /D %%G in (*.admin) DO (
  SET User=%%G
  FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%K IN ('wmic useraccount where name^='!User!' get sid /format:csv') DO (
    set REGKEY=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\%%K
    reg delete "!REGKEY!" /F
    )
  RMDIR /S /Q %SystemDrive%\Users\!User!
  )

:eof
cls
```

Comment: If you check the output of wmic.exe (e.g. via Python's `subprocess.check_output`), you'll see that line breaks are CRCRLF instead of CRLF. You can remove the trailing carriage return that remains in `%K` by assigning it to an environment variable and stripping off the last character, e.g. `set sid=%%K` and then `set REGKEY=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\!sid:~0,-1!`.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your intention, the user profile tree is not available for access by other users and removing a name from profilelist does not strike me as anything worthwhile. Either delete the profile or leave the profile information alone, _the majority of which will be recreated at next login with quite an initialisation delay._

Comment: Thanks eryksun it works great !